# ld different behaviour between two computers

Tags: c++, linux

I am trying to compile a program with the option `-l:/path/to/library` of `ld` but on one computer `ld` manage to find the library and on another it can't find it.

I found that the problem is that in the second computer, `ld` add paths to the beginning of the given one but I don't understand why it does that.

Does anyone have a solution to this ?

Comment: `-l` doesn't work with paths.

Comment: "adds paths"? What do you mean by adding multiple paths to another path? I can't understand

Comment: Let's say I'm doing -l:/usr/lib/libc.so.
ld will try to load /usr/lib//usr/lib/libc.so then /lib//usr/lib/libc.so etc.

Comment: Hawaya is libc.so not a symlink or a linker script? In the elf file you should put the actual lib name as specified by the lib's SONAME

Comment: The library i'm trying to load is indeed a symlink but I use cmake to generate the Makefile so I don't choose the parameter of the compiler.

Comment: Does the file after "-l:" actually exist? And if it is a symlink, does it point to a file that actually exists?

Comment: @JosefStark if it's a symlink, I'm not even sure whether `ld` will resolve it to the actual runtime library name (soname). The purpose of `-l:` kindof is "i'm smarter than you linker", so when there's a symlink level in between, I guess it could be problematic

Comment: The symlink exists and the file behind the symlink exists.
I'm pretty sure ld doesn't care if a file is a symlink or not, the symlink will be solved by the kernel when ld will try to open it.

Comment: Well, do you have any more information of what goes wrong? Error output? What does `make` say, what does `cmake` say? You should almost always include such output, and I should've asked that earlier, otherwise we can just _guess_ what's going wrong.

Comment: There is no cmake error and the make output this

`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liburdfdom_sensor.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liburdfdom_model_state.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liburdfdom_model.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liburdfdom_world.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libconsole_bridge.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinyxml.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libconsole_bridge.so`

Comment: @hawaya normally with -l, ld opens the file that you pass it and looks for the soname. The soname is written as a dependency, not anything that you pass to -l. If you copy libc.so.6 to libwhatever.so and pass -lwhatever, still the kernel will want to load libc.so.6 at runtime. My point was that I'm not certain about what happens for -l:

Answer (score 3):

`-l` is just for specifying names of a library. E.g. if you write `-lfoo`, gcc looks for libfoo: First the dynamic version, i.e. `libfoo.so`, and if it doesn't find it, then for the static one, i.e. `libfoo.a`.
It is *not* for including the path.

But *where* does gcc then look for my libfoo.so, you ask?
It uses some standard paths, which may be different on your two PCs, so that it works on one and it doesn't on the other. To suggest more library search paths, use the parameter `-L`. It can appear multiple times.

Example: `gcc ... -lfoo -lbar -L/my/path/to/libraries1 -L/my/second/library/path` looks for `libfoo.so` and `libbar.so` (and maybe `libfoo.a` and `libbar.a`) inside the standard search directories *as well as* the custom directories `/my/path/to/libraries1` and `/my/second/library/path`.

Comment: What is the purpose of putting ":" before the name? I was in the impression that it allows literal path specifications.

Comment: I use cmake to generate Makefile so I don't choose the parameters of compilation.

Comment: -l: Is actually for passing the path, my mistake. It seems however to be not supported on all platforms and versions, as may be the case on your second PC, or maybe the path is wrong, or the library just isn't installed there.

Comment: The library exists. But it might be a problem of version because I just see that one computer is using version 2.4 and the other 2.5.

Answer (score 0):

The man page for `ld`'s -l option says

> If namespec is of the form
>              :filename, ld will search the library path for a file called filename, otherwise it will search the library path for a file called libnamespec.a.

This says to me that the path after the : will attempt to be found *in the library search path*. So, the path is interpreted as a path relative to each of the paths in the library search path. Try to add a `-L/` to your linker statement. This will add the root dir to the link-time search path, then the linker will search for `-l:/path/to/library` in the root dir, making it act as if it was an absolute path.

Checking the library search path using `ld --verbose | grep SEARCH` on each of the computers may give you a clue why one works and the other does not. For me, there is no / in the library search dir results, and I cannot link to absolute paths without specifying `-L/`.